# Variation of the metric under the coordinate transformation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, variational-principle

Under the coordinate transformation $\bar x=x+\varepsilon$, the metric in new coordinates is:
$$
\bar g^{\mu\nu}(\bar x)=g^{\alpha\beta}(x)\frac{\partial \bar x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial \bar x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}=g^{\mu\nu}(x)+g^{\mu\beta}\frac{\partial \varepsilon^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}+g^{\alpha\nu}\frac{\partial \varepsilon^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}
$$

By expanding $\bar g^{\mu\nu}(\bar x)$ to the first order of $\varepsilon$
$$
\bar g^{\mu\nu}(\bar x)=\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x+\varepsilon)=\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x)+\frac{\partial{\bar g^{\mu\nu}}}{\partial\varepsilon^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}
$$
The variation of the metric under such a transformation is:
$$
\delta g^{\mu\nu}(x)=\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x)-g^{\mu\nu}(x)=-\frac{\partial{ g^{\mu\nu}}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}+ g^{\mu\beta}\frac{\partial \varepsilon^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}+g^{\alpha\nu}\frac{\partial \varepsilon^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}
$$

## My question is

**Why is**  $\dfrac{\partial{\bar g^{\mu\nu}}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}$ **considered to be equal to** $\dfrac{\partial{ g^{\mu\nu}}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}$ **?**

I rewrite it in detail:
$$
\bar g^{\mu\nu}(\bar x)=\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x+\varepsilon)=\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x+\varepsilon)|_{\varepsilon=0}+\frac{\partial{\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x+\varepsilon)}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial \bar x^{\alpha}}|_{\varepsilon=0}\varepsilon^{\alpha}=
$$
$$\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x)+\frac{\partial{\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x)}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}
$$
And why is $$\frac{\partial{\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x)}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}=\frac{\partial{g^{\mu\nu}(x)}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}?$$

Comment: why in the first equation are not the partial derivatives of epsilon multiplied by metric?

Comment: How you got your first equation?

Comment: I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you work in first order in $\varepsilon$. So you need to consider only the linear terms in $\varepsilon$:

$$
\delta g^{\mu\nu}(x)=\bar g^{\mu\nu}(x)-g^{\mu\nu}(x)=-\frac{\partial{ \bar{g}^{\mu\nu}}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\varepsilon^{\alpha}+ \frac{\partial \varepsilon^{\mu}}{\partial x_{\nu}}+\frac{\partial \varepsilon^{\nu}}{\partial x_{\mu}}
$$

So $g^{\mu\nu}$ and $\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}$ differ only in first order in $\varepsilon$.

And because we work in linear order, we have

$$
\frac{\partial\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\partial x^\alpha} \varepsilon^\alpha= 
\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\partial x^\alpha}\varepsilon^\alpha + O(\varepsilon)
$$

Comment: $\bar g^{\mu\nu}$ is different from $g^{\mu\nu}$. So are their derivatives wrt. $\varepsilon$. They are inconsistent.

Comment: It looks like in general $$\frac{\partial \bar F(x)}{\partial x^{\alpha}}=\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$$ Why they must be equal? $\bar F(x)$ and $F(x)$ are different.

Comment: I update answer.

Comment: Even more explicitly is it $$\bar g^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}+C\varepsilon$$ $$\frac{\partial \bar g^{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}|_{\varepsilon=0}=\left(\frac{\partial g^{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}+\frac{\partial C\varepsilon}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right)|_{\varepsilon=0}?$$